# Rails find order id on mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

On a order mailer to find the order id i used order_id, but rails return a error, if i use params the same.

what's the way to get find the object id on a mailer?

```
def order_confirmation(order)
    order = Order.find(order_id)
    @user = order.buyer_id
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Confirmação da Compra', &:html)
  end
```

Comment: If the `order` you pass (instance) is already an `Order` (class) then there is no point in "finding" it again. Since you assign the result to whatever you got it will be lost for good. Try omitting the line `order = Order.find(order_id)` completely

Comment: Btw: You probably do `not` want to assign an instance variable of your mailer. Even if `order` was an `Order` `buyer_id` would likely be a `FixNum` and would not understand `#email` at all. If the user is to be taken from the `order` it would likely by `order.buyer` (without the `id`).

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in an instance of `order` as a parameter, but you don't pass `order_id` or otherwise try to derive it before you use it.

Maybe you should try replacing

```
order = Order.find(order_id)
```

with

```
order = Order.find(order.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

As MarsAtomic mentioned you are passing a whole order with "order"

```
def order_confirmation(order)  # order contains the order itself 
    order = Order.find(order_id) #order_id is not specified
    @user = order.buyer_id
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Confirmação da Compra', &:html)
end
```

You want to send the ID of the order which you can accomplish like this:

```
def order_confirmation(order)
    order_identification = order.order_id   # now order contains the ID number of the order
    @user = order.buyer_id
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Confirmação da Compra', &:html)
  end
```

On this line, "order" already contains the order record. If you want the id (order.id), if you want the buyer_id (order.buyer_id), if you want the order_id (order.order_id):

```
def order_confirmation(order)
```

I recommend renaming order to something else (I did "order_identification") because you are passing order as a parameter and using the same parameter inside would overwrite it.